# Does .join method change the array into string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, join, methods

The result for `.join` is different from `.push` or `.pop`.

```js
var mack=[];

mack.push("dog", "cat");
mack.join(" ");

alert(mack);
```

Console.log: ["dog", "cat"]

---

```js
var mack=[];

mack.push("dog", "cat");

alert(mack.join(" "));
```

Console.log: "dog cat"

---

In the first one, `mack.join(" ");` does not change the original `mack` array, unlike `mack.push("dog", "cat");` or `mack.pop();`.

I'm curious that why this happened. And is there any other method like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Push` and `pop` methods are used on `Array` object to add or remove data to/from Array and therefore change Array itself.

`Join` method doesn't change `Array`, it returns `String` - new object, Array remains unchanged as it is. It could be used e.g. for concatenating Strings which are put in array with particular character.

More about arrays could be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp

Answer (score 3):

The `join()` function doesn't change the element of array that's only represent the array  elements as **string** with the separator what we give as argument.
here is the reference of join function 
[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Array **push** and **pop** is use to add or remove element from a array that return array new size for push and element for POP.

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

[Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Here the array elements are ok as you pushed on it.

```js
var mack=[];

    mack.push("dog", "cat");

var mack_string = mack.join(" ");

console.log(mack); // Array [ "dog", "cat" ]

console.log(mack_string); // "dog cat"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `join()` method joins all elements of an array into a string, [detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

It returns a string and *does not modify the original array.*
 Also it does not make sense to assign `String` for `Array` object, if that was your expectation.